# Determining type of object

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

If I have this scenario :

```
interface Node {}

class EmptyNode implements Node {}

class NotEmptyNode implements Node {}
```

And now I have another class,

```
class List {
  Node n;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is find a way to determine a way to get the size of list of nodes. I already have the logic down :

```
public int getSize(Node start) {
    if (start==EmptyNode) {  //Can't do this, not sure how to check if its an empty Node
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1 + getSize(start.next()); //Want to add 1 and move to next Node
    }
}
```

Since EmptyNode and NotEmptyNode are both types of a Node, I know I need to implement a function that I can write in the interface which will be implemented in both the classes and be able to figure when the end of the list has been hit.

Comment: `instanceof` is what you are looking for

Comment: Yeah, I looked into that but is there any way around that?

Comment: You either need to use .equals() or .instanceof(), == compares hash codes in Java

Comment: @Gala Yeah, I thought of using operators you've mentioned but is there a cleaner way to go about it using OO rules?

Comment: `NotEmptyNode implements Apple`? What's `Apple`? And what is `SNode`? Assuming these are typos, you could use `start instanceof Node`.

Comment: for such scenarios instanceof  is useful. Why are you not interested for using  that ?

Comment: @Darshit I wanted to get a cleaner look at the more so object oriented way just to get more so of idea how to approach such situations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're working with instances here. That means you could just put an `isEmpty()` method in your node interface, and use that to check if the node is empty.

```
interface Node {
    boolean isEmpty();
}

class EmptyNode implments Node {
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() { return true; }
}

class NotEmptyNode implements Node {
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() { return false; }
}

...

public int getSize(Node start) {
    if (start.isEmpty()) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

Another solution is to have `Node` implement a `size()` function:

```
interface Node {
    int size();
    Node next();
}

class EmptyNode implements Node {
    @Overide
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }
    ...
}

class NotEmptyNode implements Node {
    @Overide
    public int size() {
        return 1 + next().size();
    }
    ...
}

...

class List {
    Node n;

    public int getSize() {
        return n.size();
    }
}
```

Which gets rid of the `if`statement altogother.